# how can i stored resized image from timthumb

Tags: php, timthumb

i am using timthumb. 
How can I stored the resized image into a separate folder?
I tried to look at the CONFIG, but have not clue where the resized imaged is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a caching folder, timthumb default to the dir the timthumb library is in. But you will have to create an empty folder called cache yourself.

On [this](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2012/03/timthumb-configs/) page they made a list of constants you can specify, like cache true/false and the caching directory.